# Install OpenJDK 14 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am trying to install OpenJDK 14 in `Ubuntu 18.04` using `tar.gz`, using following steps
and referring to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764849/how-can-i-install-jdk-8u91-linux-x64-tar-gz-on-ubuntu).

1. Extracted the file using

   $ sudo tar xvzf openjdk-14.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -C /usr/java
2. Now setting `JAVA_HOME` through `$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-14.0.1/bin/java`

   $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/java 20000

   $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/javac 20000
3. Now by running

   $ sudo update-alternatives --config java  , I get

[image]

4. But still, when I run `java -version` , I am getting this

[image]

even though `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to `jdk-14`

Even in `nano. bashrc` I have set environment variable

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-14.0.1/bin/java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?